# Address into database on google map

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some address of peoples into my database (in a table named missions, the field is address)

I have also a function geocoder to change this address into long and lat to draw a marker on my map.

This only stuff I don't understand how to do is to take my address from my database and use it into my map

Here is my code : (EDIT)

I want to take the address from my database and put it in the field 'adress' in my geocoder function. But is that possible to do it ? if yes how ?

Thanks for helping guys. (Hope i'm clear ^^')

EDIT :

My .js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // When the window has finished loading create our google map below

    var map;
    var geocoder;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-geo'), mapOptions);

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.376018, 4.901962),
                    radius: 500,
                    map: map
                });

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                accuracy = parseFloat(position.coords.accuracy);
                map.setZoom(14);
                circle.setCenter(pos);
                circle.setRadius(accuracy);
                map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    content: 'Voici votre géolocalisation'
                });

            //map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function() {
            circle.setMap(null);
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to a page that prints the address.
            url: "addMarkers.php",  //url for the address page                    
            success: function(result){
                var adresse = result; //create a variable and give it the value of the response data
                codeAddress(adresse); //decode the address using codeAddress into Lat and Lon
            }
        });
        codeAddress(<?php echo $adresse; ?>);
        //codeAddress();
    }

    function codeAddress(adresse) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "61 rue de la libération, 44230, saint sebastien sur loire"}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
      if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
      } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
      }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And my .php

```
<?php
require_once("../admin/php/checklogin.php");
$host_name  = "my_host";
$database   = "my_db";
$bdduser_name  = "my_name";
$bddpassword   = "my_bddpass";

mysql_connect($host_name, $bdduser_name, $bddpassword) or die ("connection impossible.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("connection bdd impossible.");
//tu fais la connexion à la base puis:

$sql="SELECT `id`, `nom`, `adresse`, `esc`, `cp`, `ville`
FROM `missions` WHERE 1"; //remplaces par tes noms

ini_set('mysql.trace_mode', true); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 

$result = mysql_query($sql); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Just for your info, *adress* should read address (in English).

Comment: Yep, i put only one d in all the explication, but i have 2 d in the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could use a [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request (would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to a php file on the server to retrieve the address information.

```
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to a page that prints the address.
    url: "getAddress.php",  //url for the address page                    
    success: function(response){                    
        var address = response; //create a variable and give it the value of the response data
        codeAddress(address); //decode the address using codeAddress into Lat and Lon
    }
});
```

The second but less clean way to do it in my opinion is too directly echo the address variable from php to javascript.

```
   codeAddress(<?php echo $address; ?>);
```

I hope I pointed you into the right direction. You should be able to achieve your goal if you have a average understanding of PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Thanks bro for the exemples, I will try when you post it and answer after if it's work ;-)

Comment: I edited my answer. Good luck with your project and remember to have fun programming :)

Comment: Definitely go for option 1!

Comment: @koenvdheuvel I edit my first post, with my .php this time ^^. I forgot about the postal code and the city to put in my js file. I think I put your code in the good place, but maybe not ? (And no problem for having fun, it's funny :) )

Comment: Good Job. Happy to help.